# Can't Load URL in FB Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[image]Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I'm getting this error after upgrading my graph version to 2.7 to 2.9.

Can anyone please help me out why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Have you researched it? Is has been discussed a lot of times before already ... And what _do_ your app settings look like, do you have the relevant data input into the field the message mentions?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I have relevant data into the input field mentioned app domain as devapp.abc.com

Comment: Double-check that you used the correct app id in your code (and that you use it as a string value only) - that is another common cause for this error showing.

Comment: Btw., that rather sounds like an error you would be getting from the JS SDK, not the PHP one.

Comment: No luck, I have altered all settings as well

Comment: Well then show us a screenshot of the actual settings, please.

Comment: When I said _actual_, I meant without relevant parts blanked out ... Is your test site publicly reachable? If so, please share the URL.

Comment: I got it working. My application was not public I switched it to public also I changed the redirect URL.